# making an arraylist that uses a name that is already a variable

Tags: variables, arraylist

I am doing an assignment where for one of the methods, I want to create a new arraylist everytime the method is called.

Here is my method

```
`public boolean addMember(java.lang.String id)
 {
    boolean answer=true;

if(palBookMembers.size()==maxSize) {
    answer=false;
}

else {
    palBookMembers.add(id);
    members++;
    ArrayList<String> id  = new ArrayList<String>();
    answer=true;
}

return answer;
```

}

I am getting an error when I try to make an ArrayList that has the same name as the java.lang.String id variable. But, everytime this method is called I want to make an ArrayList that has a name that is unique to the id so I can use it later. For example, if the id was "Steve" I would be okay with the arrayList being called "steveId", but I just don't know how to name the arrayList this way. I tried doing 
ArrayList id + "Id" = new ArrayList();
to make a name like that, but it still said the variable id was already being used. So basically, how can I name an arrayList based on the inputted id that would be unique every time the addMember method is called.

Comment: I had trouble wording this question so if there is anyway I could clarify it I would love to

Answer (score 1):

Maintain a `Map` keyed by `id` and `put` the new list into the map with a key of id.

Comment: hi, im sorry we haven't learned about maps in class yet. is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the line "ArrayList id  = new ArrayList();" is useless.
What are you trying to do?